# Gulp Jade and HTML templates

Tags: angularjs, node.js, gulp, pug

I have an AngularJS project that I have existing HTML templates and I want to also start using Jade templates. I want to create a single gulp task for the templates, but I am not sure how I can skip the Jade step for HTML files. Here is what I have:

```
gulp.task('templates', function () {
    return gulp.src('./client/views/**/*.{html, jade}')
        .pipe(jade())
        .pipe(htmlmin({
            collapseWhitespace: true,
            removeComments: true
        }))
        .pipe(templateCache({
            root: 'views/',
            module: 'omApp'
        })) 
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./client/dist/scripts/templates'));
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`gulp-if`](https://github.com/robrich/gulp-if):

```
gulp.task('templates', function () {
return gulp.src('./client/views/**/*.{html, jade}')
    .pipe(gulpif(function(file) { 
        return /jade$/.test(file.path); 
    }, jade()))
    ....
```